# Integrating vue-auth-image plugin into Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to integrate [vue-auth-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-auth-image) plugin to Nuxt.js.

In **plugins/auth-images.js**:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'                                                                                                                            
import VueAuthImage from 'vue-auth-image'                                                                                                        
import axios from 'axios'                                                                                                                        
Vue.use(VueAuthImage)                                                                                                                            

if (process.browser) {                                                                                                                           
  const authHeader = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('my-own-id-token')                                                                         
  axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = authHeader                                                                                       
}
```

In **nuxt.config.js**, I call this plugin:

```
plugins: [                                                                                                                                     
  '@/plugins/auth-images'                                                                                                                   
]
```

Later in my code, I apply this:

```html
<img v-auth-img="link/to/my/api/endpoint">
```

In the console I get this:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: auth-img

How to fix this?

Comment: You named the file `auth-images.js` so there's a typo in your config `@/plugins/auth-images` instead of `@/plugins/vauth-images`.

Comment: Thanks for the attention, and sorry, I just did the typo here, in my actual code I did not and I used a different name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive is not auth-img, but auth-image, so correct code is:

```
<img v-auth-image=
```